# how to cut images in corona to have jigsaw like this?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

**THIS IS ANSWERED NOW :)**

I'm building a jigsaw game, I have no problem with programming it if the images are cut with photoshop, no problem..

today, I have an image taken by camera

I want to slice this image into jigsaw pieces dynamically, inside the corona script.

can `corona masking` feature do this?

I want to have these pieces as `separate objects`, can I do this with corona SDK? How?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer:

yes masks are enough and it's easy, it worked very nice!

Code

```
MJ = display.newImage("MJ.jpg",200,200)

MJ.width = 300
MJ.height = 300

mask = graphics.newMask( "mask.png" )

MJ:setMask( mask )
```

arbitrary mask I created

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest method would be to generate masks for each puzzle and simply generate X instances of image and mask each one with another mask. You may add a `object.id` or `object.column` and `object.row` to determine their index or position.

Here's a masking tutorial for you:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/media/imageMask/index.html

Comment: thanks alot, I added my experiment with code and mask and result.

Comment: If you will ever have problems with mask, there's a 90% chance it's one of these:
- The mask image must have width and height dimensions that are divisible by 4.
- The mask image must be bordered by at least 3 pixels of black space on all four sides. You may need to increase the overall size of your mask image to include this border.
- If the mask image is smaller than the target image, the region outside of the mask bounds will be fully masked (transparent).